# Embed autoplay false not working in Mozilla

Tags: html, firefox, embed, mozilla, autoplay

I am using embed tag in Mozilla. Video start playing on page load only. Autoplay (**autoplay="false"**) is not helping me. Can any one help me please?

Thanks in advance !

```
<embed id="video1" src="Wildlife.wmv" type="application/mediaplayer" autoplay="false" width="470" height="280"></embed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know bug for Chrome and Firefox. Try using another source extension, `.wmv` is also not valid for Mac users without `Flip4mac`.

Also this bug can be fixed by using `<object>` like this:

```
<object width="470" height="280" type="application/x-mplayer2">
  <param name="fileName" value="Wildlife.wmv">
  <param name="autostart" value="0">
</object>
```

The bug in the `<embed>` can be caused by using the wrong `type`, so move on to the better solution:

---

### Best solution in this case

Then again, the best solution for using `<embed>` is setting the `plugin url`, `type` and `autostart` like this:

```
<embed type="video/x-ms-wmv" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" autostart="0" width="470" height="280" loop="0" src="Wildlife.wmv"></embed>
```