# autostart does not work with embed tag

Tags: html, html5-video

I am using **Laravel PHP** to create a blog application that retrieves and displays images and videos from blogs depending on what's stored in the database.  I'm using a single '**embed**' tag to display the images and videos and they are retrieved just fine.

However, whenever a video is retrieved and displayed in my view, it automatically starts playing.  I've tried setting the '**autostart**' attribute to '**false**' but it is not working.

**View**:

```
<div class="blog_img_container_image">     
    <embed src='{{ asset("uploads/photos/" . $funnyblocks_blog->blog_photo_path ) }}' width="300" autostart="false"> 
    </embed><br>
    <p> {{ $funnyblocks_blog->blog_content}} </p>
</div>
```

Is there some attribute I'm missing or an easier way to accomplish this task?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should check the type of the data and use right syntax. For images `<img src=...>` and for the movies for example: `<embed type="video/x-ms-wmv" [...] autostart="0">`

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286541/html-embed-autoplay-false-but-still-plays-automatically or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768710/embed-autoplay-false-not-working-in-mozilla? Could be `autostart="0"`

Comment: @Sean Yes I have looked at that question and that solution doesn't work for me when I add 'type=video/mp4' and autostart="0"

Comment: This link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768710/embed-autoplay-false-not-working-in-mozilla